# Data for experiments of Doppler effect

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, physics, mathematical-modeling

I am a high school student that has attempted to carry out the experiment for the Doppler effect using an RC car going at constant speed, a sound source at constant frequency and phyphox app to measure the change in frequency. Unfortunately my experiment didn’t work as planned due to the noise from the RC car and so my data wasn’t good to be analyzed. What I’m trying to do with this data is to analyze rate of change, maxima, minima and really understanding properties of graphs and maybe coming up with a general formula for the graph at certain intervals. I am proposing you if you can please aid me with already measured data of frequency shift so I can use in my analysis.

Thanks to everyone for your help.

Comment: This is not really on topic for this site, I would suggest looking for such data in a search engine.

Comment: How did you take the data? Does the app you used tell you the dominant sound frequency that the microphone detects or do you have an audio recording of the experiment? If you have an audio recording, you can filter out (or simply ignore) the frequencies far away from your test frequency using an FFT and track how far the frequency peak moves. The Doppler shifts you should see will be very small unless you used speeds comparable to the speed of sound (unlikely with an RC car) or unless you used high frequencies on the speaker.